# error while creating new project

Tags: android, xml

Good Day everyone

I am beginning android developer. And I have stacked at the beginning. I followed all instructions from *developer.android.com*. When I create **new android application project**, then `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` is red underlined. I imported it from my sdk folder. Moreover, I have error in my XML files which have location at
`my_project_name/res/`, folders: `values/styles.xml, values-v11/styles.xml, values-v14/styles.xml`.

After importing `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`, self generated **R** class is not generated. In case I disable all errors, I will have again this issue when I newly create android project. It tooks me a lot of time to manually improve it. Does anybodly help me to improve once and use for ever:).

Kind regards

Comment: remome adt pluging and install again

Comment: If you are new in android development. try Android studio. Its the official IDE now

Comment: Well, *Android Studio* is still in **beta**, but it IS stated on the website that *ADT* is **no longer developed**, so it will become deprecated once Android Studio properly comes out, I'm guessing. But **ADT** is downloadable here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and **Android Studio** here https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: I think all you would need to do is download the ADT again, make sure you are using a non-AndroidWear SDK version such as API 19, and if you want to use ActionBarActivity then just start the new project with min SDK level 8, max SDK level 19, and use navigation type of `Navigation Drawer`. That sets up the project properly, if Eclipse has the right to create the folders it needs in the workspace directory.